# Correct Placement/Best Practices of Require/library calls in R when using a loop

Tags: r, recursion, while-loop

I have a function in R that uses a few libraries.  I have put the call to those libraries in the function itself.  This function may be called a number of times when the main part of the program is running.  The function plots data, which I may or may not want to run.

Is this a problem?  I am thinking it is better to call the library via require or library once.  However, it doesn't make sense to put the library call in the main part of the program because the function may not be called at all.

The function is here:

```
CreateChartOfStrikeTimes <- function(Symbol)
{
  filename = paste(Symbol, "All Strikes.csv", sep=" ")
  data = read.csv(filename, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  colnames(data) <- c("Date", "Strike Crossed")
  data$hour <- as.numeric(strftime(data$Date, format="%H"))

   library(reshape)
   hourcount <- melt(table(data$hour))  
  colnames(hourcount) <- c("Hour", "Strike.Crosses")

  library(ggplot2)
  chart <- ggplot(hourcount, aes(x = Hour, y = Strike.Crosses)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    labs(title=paste(Symbol,"Number of Strike Crosses Across All Fridays", sep=" "),
         x = "Hour Of Day In Which Cross Occurred",
         y = "Num Of Strike Crosses"
         ) +
    geom_text(aes(label = Strike.Crosses, y = Strike.Crosses+1), size = 4) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = hourcount$Hour)

  ggsave(filename=paste(Symbol, ".pdf", sep=""), plot=chart, width=11, height=8.5,
         units="in")
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Neither will reload a namespace which is already loaded, so it's adding only minimal overhead for the "is it loaded" check for each call. From the `help(library)` page info, you probably should use `require` since "*`require` is designed for use inside other functions; it returns `FALSE` and gives a warning (rather than an error as `library()` does by default) if the package does not exist.*"

Comment: `require` is designed for use inside functions. `reshape` is an old package, you should upgrade to `reshape2`. You might not even need it if you are doing a simple melt. There are base functions, `reshape`, `stack`/`unstack`, which may give what you want without loading a package. They won't reload again so I don't see a problem with what you are doing especially if this is just a personal, local function. Also, you could do something like `if (plot) {require(ggplot2) more code}` to avoid loading ggplot if you don't want to plot

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr.  I have begun using require for my functions this past week.